# 301 redirect in .htaccess places default.html in url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I migrated my website using a CMS backup/restore which moved my site while preserving folder structure and URLs. and i proceeded to add a 301 redirect as follows:

```
RedirectMatch 301 aquaponics(.*) http://www.circulatingaquaponics.com/$1
```

the redirect works but adds a default.html in the end of the URL which gives me a 404 error

how do i remove the default.html?

Comment: Nothing wrong in this rule, `default.html` is probably set in `DirectoryIndex` on new site.

Comment: Do you have other rules in your htaccess file? Can you post the entire file?

Comment: Thanks, somehow it worked when i erased the command and re-did it

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Have you learned anything else about this?